# AWS ALB returns 503 but nothing is in access logs and in its ELB_5XXs metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

**The problem**
We occasionally get 503 which seems to be happening from AWS ALB, however it isn't showing any metric bump or has nothing in access logs.

**Important note**:
this is happening only a couple of times during the day for random endpoints. Application is handling millions of requests without any problems but sometimes just a couple (4 for example) return 503.

**More details**:
Request is originating from users, from WebBrowsers (US based, different browsers). CloudFront gets the request and in its logs I can see 503 with "OriginError". Then CloudFront calls API Gateway (HTTP). In its logs I can see 503 with small (milliseconds) response times (both for full response and for integration). Also custom JWT authorizer (Lambda) is logging this request as successful (allowed).

Integration is Fargate service with Python app (with uwsgi+Flask) proxied by nginx container. I have detailed logging enabled for nginx, uwsgi and flask. There are no 503s reported by any of them.

On ALB: there were no unhealthy hosts at the time 503 happened. And also desired number of healthy hosts were present. Number of requests indicates a spike (2-3x times of typical threshold) that happened about ~2 minutes before 503. ALB access logs have zero `elb_status_code` with 503 and zero with `target_status_code`. Also ALB metrics are showing zero data points in metric named `ELB_5XXs` and in `HTTP_503s`. `Target Connection Errors` are zero. Zero rejected connections.

Is there anything else I can check to figure out what could be the problem? May it be related to AWS ALB scaling? Would it return 503 in this case?